# Restart Browser After Every Feature File

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I would like my Protractor- CucumberJS framework to start browser at the start of every feature file - load the URL - execute scenarios - close the browser once all scenarios are done executing - launch fresh browser instance for next feature file...and so on.

I am using `Beforefeature` hook to launch URL and `Afterfeature` hook to do browser.quit()

Tried setting `shardTestFiles` to true in `multiCapabilities`. It does launch a separate browser for every feature file but throws error - `NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.`

Setting `restartBrowserBetweenTests` to `true` in config file closes and opens browser instance for every scenario - not what I want.

How can this be accomplished?