# How to make cucumber instantiating Custom World for every Feature instead of every Scenario?

Tags: bdd, cucumberjs

I have a Feature where the Scenarios in the Feature file is logically interconnected - hence my Scenarios cannot be run independently.

**Nice:** I created a CustomWorld to let Cucumber create and destroy the instance of my framework by itself.

**Bad:** Cucumber creates and destroys the instance for every scenario. But I want it to be created and destroyed for every feature instead of scenarios.

**Here is my feature file**

```
Feature: Table Headers

  Scenario: Check the default headers ### My framework instance created here
    Given I log in to the application ### A setup
    When I navigate to the list page
    Then the table should have the below headers
      | Default Headers |
      | First Name |
      | Last Name  |
      | Age        |

  Scenario: Add columns ### want to reuse the instance created above and destroy automatically after this scenario
    When I add the below columns to display
      | Headers |
      | City    |
      | Country |
    Then the table should have the below headers
      | Default Headers |
      | First Name |
      | Last Name  |
      | Age        |
      | City    |
      | Country |
    And I log out from the application ### A teardown
```

*A bite of my framework:*
When I create an instance of my class, a selenium webdriver instance would be created, opens a browser and launches URL.

**The real problem:** I want to open the browser and launch URL only once per feature and not for every scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This is breaking the rules of BDD and cucumber. You should not have dependencies across Scenario. What I would suggest is that your `Given` or `Background` do the setup and that steps are NOT explicit.

```
Given I am on the list page
  |Application|
  |###|
Then the table should have the below headers
  | Default Headers |
  | First Name |
  | Last Name  |
  | Age        |

Given I am on the list page
  |Application|
  |###|
When I add the below columns to display
  | Headers |
  | City    |
  | Country |
Then the table should have the below headers
  | Default Headers |
  | First Name |
  | Last Name  |
  | Age        |
  | City    |
  | Country |
```

Also your final And is not a step and should not be included in your Scenario it should be part of AfterHook

Comment: Got it. Yes, my context is violating BDD rules. At the same time, opening browser, log in to my application for every scenario is too expensive.

Comment: I wish not to repeat the setup for every scenario but for every feature. Here is another use case - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904082/restart-browser-after-every-feature-file?rq=1

Comment: You don't need to kill your browser for every scenario. The browser is separate from the world instance.